# Java - How to list content of a directory?

Tags: java

I want to display the content of the directory /etc/yum.repos.d in Centos. Usually in this directory is stored information about repositories from which Centos downloads RPM packages.
What is the proper way to display the content of a directory in Java?

Best wishes

Comment: Please edit your old question instead of creating new similar ones.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: I want to view a question that can't be easily solved by a four-word Google search. Guess I'll have to keep looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dir {
   static int indentLevel = -1;

   static void listPath(File path) {
   File files[]; 
   indentLevel++; 

   files = path.listFiles();

   Arrays.sort(files);
   for (int i = 0, n = files.length; i < n; i++) {
      for (int indent = 0; indent < indentLevel; indent++) {
         System.out.print("  ");
      }
      System.out.println(files[i].toString());
      if (files[i].isDirectory()) {

      listPath(files[i]);
    }
  }
indentLevel--; 
}

 public static void main(String args[]) {
    listPath(new File("/etc/yum.repos.d"));
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example :

```
File directory = new File("/etc/yum.repos.d");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
File dir = new File("some_directory");
String[] filesAndSubdirs = dir.list();
```